# Deprecated `withDelimiter(char)` in CSVFormat

Tags: java, csv

I have some code that uses the Apache Commons CSV library for working with CSV data. I noticed that the `withDelimiter(char)` method in `CSVFormat` is deprecated. Can someone please explain why it's deprecated and what's the recommended alternative way to specify the delimiter?

Here's an example of my code:

```java
try (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(sw, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(';'))) {
    // ...
}
```

I'm using `withDelimiter(';')` to set the delimiter to a semicolon. What should I use instead to achieve the same result without using the deprecated method?

Thank you!

Comment: It's explained in [the javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withDelimiter-char-). You are supposed to use the `CSVFormat.Builder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CSVFormat.Builder.setDelimiter(char)` instead, like [@Jorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8681/jorn) commented, it's explained in [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withDelimiter-char-):

> `@Deprecated`
> `public CSVFormat withDelimiter(char delimiter)`
> ***Deprecated.** Use `CSVFormat.Builder.setDelimiter(char)`*

You can do this way:

```java
try (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(sw, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.builder().setDelimiter(';').build())) {
    // ...
}
```